# ncurses multi colors on screen

Tags: c, command-line, window, ncurses

I want to make a menu with `ncurses.h` and more than one color.
I mean something like this:

```
┌────────────────────┐
│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│ <- color 1
│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒│ <- color 2
└────────────────────┘
```

But if I use `init_pair()`, `attron()`and `attroff()` the color of the whole screen is the same, and not like I've expected.

```
initscr();

init_pair(0, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);

attron(0);
printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");
refresh();

attron(1);
printw("And this in a green background!\n");
refresh()    

sleep(2);

endwin();
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a working version:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    start_color();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    printw("And this in a green background!\n");
    refresh();

    getch();

    endwin();
}
```

Notes:

- you need to call `start_color()` after `initscr()` to use color.
- you have to use the `COLOR_PAIR` macro to pass a color pair allocated with `init_pair` to `attron` et al.
- you can't use color pair 0.
- you only have to call `refresh()` once, and only if you want your output to be seen at that point, *and* you're not calling an input function like `getch()`.

[This HOWTO](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=curses%20howto&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF0QFjAA&url=http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/&ei=MxyoT7uvCc2biQenjPnLAw&usg=AFQjCNEvip2fQeZ8sCtDw0BoHAtmL7Uf6w&cad=rja) is very helpful.

Comment: instead of printw, why can't be mvwprintw??

Comment: @jorgesaraiva Possibly because there's no need for it? I mean, sure, you _can_ specify exactly what window to print to and where you want it, but why bother with all that when the behavior of `printw("...\n")` does what you need?

Comment: Is it possible to use `CUSTOM_COLOR` with r,g,b instead of `COLOR_RED` and if yes how should one code it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize colors and use the COLOR_PAIR macro.

Color pair `0` is reserved for *default colors* so you have to start your indexing at `1`.

```
....

initscr();
start_color();

init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");

....
```