# Gnome Terminal cannot print the red color in a program using curses

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, ncurses, gnome

I am trying to get into the *ncurses* library. I am dissapointed that the Gnome Terminal can print red via ANSI escape characters but not the predefined red from *ncurses*.

```
#include <curses.h>

void init_colors() {
    int a;
    for(a = 1; a < COLORS; a++) {
        init_pair(a, a, COLOR_BLACK);
    }
}

void print_colors() {
    int a;
    for(a = 1; a < COLORS; a++) {
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(a));
        mvprintw(a, 0, "color");
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(a));
    }
}

int main() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    if(has_colors()) 
        start_color();          

    init_colors();
    print_colors();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

This should print the word "*color*" in any default *ncurses* color, but the second line (`init_pair` should initialize the second `COLOR_PAIR` as `red`) is not printed at all. It seems that Gnome Terminal simply skip this line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you print any other colors?  Or is it just red that fails?

Comment: @MooingDuck I can print any other of the predefined colors without problems: Including black, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white.

Comment: This could be a local issue or setting in your `gnome-terminal`. It works here with 3.14.2.

Answer (score -2):

This is a copy of [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487166/ncurses-multi-colors-on-screen)

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    start_color();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    printw("And this in a green background!\n");
    refresh();

    getch();

    endwin();
}
```

### Notes

- you need to call `start_color()` after `initscr()` to use color.
- you have to use the `COLOR_PAIR` macro
- to pass a color pair allocated with `init_pair` to `attron` et al.
- you can't use the color pair 0.
- you only have to call `refresh()` once,
- and only if you want your output to be seen at that point,
- and you're not calling an input function like `getch()`.

Comment: I can't really see any steps here that aren't in the OP

Comment: The OP's program worked correctly as such; a useful answer would either comment on some quirk of color themes, or mention a known bug (from bug reports).  None of the latter come to mind, imagination isn't sufficient for the former.