# ncurses (init_extended_pair): can't create more than 255 color pairs

Tags: c++, colors, terminal, console, ncurses

In version 6.1, ncurses introduce [init_extended_pair](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_extended_pair) to extend limit of possible color pairs above `short` limit. 
In my experiment everything works till value 255. For values 256 and greater, there is **no error**, but foreground and background have default values. For values 32767 and greater function return **error**.

[image]

Program return:

```
COLOR_PAIRS: 65536
                  Error: 32767
```

What is the proper why to create large number of color pairs? In my case I need at least 65536 of them. *(Tested on Ubuntu 19.04)*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

// g++ main.cpp -l:libncursesw.so.6.1 -ltinfo

int main() {
    initscr();
    start_color();

    std::cout << "COLOR_PAIRS: " << COLOR_PAIRS << std::endl;

    init_extended_color(2, 999, 0, 0);
    init_extended_color(3, 0, 999, 0);

    int pair1 = 255;
    if (init_extended_pair(pair1, 2, 3) == ERR)
        std::cout << "Error: " << pair1 << std::endl;

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(pair1));
    mvprintw(2, 1, "pair255");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(pair1));

    int pair2 = 256;
    if (init_extended_pair(pair2, 2, 3) == ERR)
        std::cout << "Error: " << pair2 << std::endl;

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(pair2));
    mvprintw(3, 1, "pair256");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(pair2));

    int pair3 = 32767; // 2^15-1
    if (init_extended_pair(pair3, 3, 2) == ERR)
        std::cout << "Error: " << pair3 << std::endl;

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(pair3));
    mvprintw(4, 1, "pair32767");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(pair3));

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding similar problem [How to enable 32k color pairs in ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985896/how-to-enable-32k-color-pairs-in-ncurses). In my case `COLOR_PAIRS` return value 65536 not 256, more over question is from 2015, and `init_extended_pair` was added to library on 2017.04.01, and [released in version 6.1 January 27, 2018](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Despite this I rebuild libncursesw6 package with `--enable-ext-colors` (`--enable-widec` was already available), but I get same result.

Comment: Hi @MarcSances, I'm afraid that's not my problem. I'm using newer API -`init_extended_pair` was not available in 2015, and `COLOR_PAIRS` is returning value `65536` not `256`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually (running this against ncurses 6.1 development), I do not see a failure from `init_extended_pair`.  At first glance, the problem appeared to be this chunk:

```
attron(COLOR_PAIR(pair3));
mvprintw(4, 1, "pair32767");
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(pair3));
```

Those **`attron`**/**`attroff`** are [legacy functions](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html). You should use **`attr_on`** and **`attr_off`**.  The *macro* form of **`attron`** and **`attroff`** (which is normally used instead of the *function*) is

```
#define wattron(win,at)         wattr_on(win, NCURSES_CAST(attr_t, at), NULL)
#define wattroff(win,at)        wattr_off(win, NCURSES_CAST(attr_t, at), NULL)
```

But in either case, the data is the "same": what fits in **`attr_t`** (a 32-bit value).  In some other functions, the color-pair is passed through separately, and ncurses 6.1 provides for passing pairs larger than 16-bits via the *opts* parameter.  These particular functions aren't extended in that way.

However, your program is returning an error for `init_extended_pair`.   That could be any of (a few) returns from [`_nc_init_pair`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/9a80fd3abd5c36bdd834b19e4c07559f6b7223d6/ncurses/base/lib_color.c#L561), but the principal one uses [`ValidPair`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/9a80fd3abd5c36bdd834b19e4c07559f6b7223d6/ncurses/new_pair.h#L104):

```
#define ValidPair(sp,pair) \
((sp != 0) && (pair >= 0) && (pair < sp->_pair_limit) && sp->_coloron)
```

To check this, I ran the code against current ncurses6, with `TERM=xterm-256color` and `TERM=xterm-direct`.   Both worked, though the `init_extended_color` in the latter fails (as expected).  I can see *that* failure by compiling ncurses with `TRACE`, and turning the trace on with `NCURSES_TRACE=0x220`.  Here's a screenshot of the trace, for example:

[image: screenshot showing ncurses traces]

The current code is available from the ncurses homepage ([here](https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/ncurses.tar.gz)). If you are able to reproduce the problem using current code, you might want to discuss it on the [bug-ncurses](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-ncurses) mailing list.  Otherwise (see mailing list), the [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses) is the reference for the version you are using.

Comment: Hi @thomas-dickey, and how should I call this two functions? In link you have provided there is note: _"...wattr_on and wattr_off are not used by this implementation except to check that they are NULL"_ (I believe that `attr_on/off` are aliases to `wattr_on/off`, and in source code `opts` is set to `GCC_UNUSED` (base/lib_wattron.c:48). Second/first problem is with `init_extended_pair` that for `pair3` return `ERR` and this problem occur before I even call `attron/off`. Note that, for `pair3` I expect inverted colors (green foreground, red background).

Comment: I don't see `TERM` mentioned.  If I run your example with `TERM=xterm-256color`, then`init_extended_pair` succeeds.  It won't work with `TERM=xterm-direct`, because the RGB palette is unchangeable.   The [package rules](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/package/debian/rules) are in the ncurses source.  As for "aliases", it helps to read `<curses.h>`...

Comment: I'm looking at the "except to check" aspect, will update answer in a while :-)

Comment: Yes, I have xterm-256color:
`echo $TERM
xterm-256color`
Maybe I will try on another distribution.

Comment: Distribution doesn't matter much: just the source-version and how you have configured ncurses.