# How can I write coloured ASCII characters directly to the console's buffer?

Tags: c++, performance, colors, io, buffer

I am a student that has become quite interested in the C++ language and I am currently working on a little project involving printing large number of coloured ASCII characters on the [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) which is an optimised version of the old `cmd.exe`. My project consists of creating small "ASCII videos" by converting frames from a video into ASCII images and printing them sequentially (see [image] or [video link](https://streamable.com/eyt2b4)). I am currently using ANSI escape sequences like `\033[38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩m` to manually set the colours I want for each ASCII character like so :

```
string char_ramp("$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\" ^ `'. ");
int brightness(some_number);

(...)

current_frame += string{} + "\033[38;2;" + to_string(r) + ";" + to_string(g) + ";" + to_string(b) + "m" + char_ramp[(int)(greyscale_index / 255 * (char_ramp.size() - 1)) / brightness] + "\033[0m";
```

Basically, I am building the frames line by line by adding the ASCII character corresponding to the current pixel's level of brightness on a grey scale character ramp and then I colourise it with an ANSI escape sequence.

But doing it this way seems to be very demanding for the terminal because I get frame drops when I print the colored ASCII frames. Say for example that if the original video was at 30 fps, the colored ASCII video would drop to roughly 15 fps.

I tried removing the colours and it seemed to be working fine, no frame drops.

Some friends suggested I should be setting the buffer data directly instead of doing all the extra logic of printing lines. However, I don't know how I could do it without changing my way of constructing the ASCII frames as I really need them to be stored in a specific way, or at least stored in a way that allows me to control the output rate. I heard that the `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` function allows me to do some things but I didn't understand how I could implement it in my code.

I don't really care about memory efficiency here so wouldn't there be a way to set the frame data into the buffer and then just iterate through the frames I want to display?

If that is just a wrong call, then what would be an efficient way of displaying these ascii frames on the terminal?

Comment: You will need to verify that the console supports the ANSI terminal escape sequences.

Comment: How many frames per second is your conversion to ASCII capable of if you remove the printing part? Feed it 60 fps and see what you get. The console printing part may be _really_ slow so just check that you've got the basic algorithm right first, then solve the display issue afterwards.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It does, as I am using the Windows Terminal (not cmd.exe)

Comment: Oh, Windows Terminal is **very** slow. Make sure your algorithm is capable of converting at 30 FPS (with some margin) and then find other means to display the result. Don't use the Windows Terminal. Make a bitmap and draw on that or something. Anything but using the terminal.

Comment: You could use multiple buffering.  Also, use `std::cout.write()` to output the buffer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Strangely enough, I measured the time it takes to print one frame and on average it's 0.023 seconds which would be equivalent to 43.47 frames per second on average, but this isn't the case, it looks like the printing part is very slow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Reminder : I am not using cmd.exe, but Windows Terminal which is already much better for my project.

Comment: Have you measured where your program spends most of its time? If your conversion algorithm is capable of making 30+ ASCII-versions in memory but you are only capable of displaying ~15, then you need other means of presenting the result. The fact that removing the colors had such a big impact seems to me like a clear hint that the presentation layer is the problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That was my question all along :/ Perhaps you didn't read my question or didn't understand some part of it. Do you need more details? Isn't writing directly to the console's buffer going to change anything?

Comment: I did read your question. I still don't know how many FPS your algorithm is capable of converting internally - before involving printing.

Comment: I also forgot to add that I am processing the frames before printing them on the terminal. I am basically storing all of the ASCII frames as strings in a vector of strings and then iterating through the strings of that vector to display them on the terminal. That way I can control the output rate of the frames. And yeah that way it also doesn't matter at which rate I'm processing the frames since I'm not outputting them as I'm processing them.

Comment: You need to profile your program to find where the bottlenecks are. You have a clear pipeline of things going on. Measure!

Comment: You may try to use WINAPI console functions like `WriteConsoleOutput`.

Comment: @MattMoissat Any question that concerns the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by the build settings used to build the program.  The most important setting is the *optimization level* you used.  If you're running a "debug" or unoptimized build, then what you are reporting is basically meaningless.

Comment: Going through a terminal with escape sequences is likely not optimal. Just draw on a canvas and present that. That is very fast - But first, **measure** where the bottlenecks are! If you haven't managed to create a conversion algorithm to produce 30+ FPS, you should work on that first.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the advice, I actually realised that the time it takes to print a frame is not a constant, sometimes it's 0.01 second and the worst case I could find is a little over 0.1 second, so it like prints at 100 fps and then suddently at 10 fps maybe that's why.
```
0.008
0.015
0.011
0.012
0.09
0.101
0.008
0.106
0.008
0.01
0.095
0.108
0.011
0.01
0.009
0.01
0.01
0.01
0.102
0.01
0.013
0.09
0.1
0.011
```
So it's definitely the printing part that's causing issues, but I don't know what to make of these numbers. They to vary pretty much randomly.

Comment: If there is a suddenly slowdown like that, I wonder if you are hitting the scrollback buffer limit of Windows Terminal.  Are you clearing the scrollback buffer every frame?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Also I'm pretty sure some dude got it working on the terminal with escape sequences. https://github.com/mariiaan/cmdplay-pp Check this github repo, specifically you want to look at Asciifier.cpp

Comment: @MattMoissat In the link you shared: https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: @Eljay How can I check that limit though,

Comment: @MattMoissat Why are you so focused on using the worst presentation media available? Sending a stream of escape sequences to be interpreted and then rendered. It's not created to be efficient for this kind of thing. Why not render it yourself when you have the information readily available?!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well it's an ASCII themed school project. Also didn't I ask already if there were any other ways to display large quantities ASCII characters efficiently in my question? It's fine if you don't have an answer to that, but I'd really like to know.

Comment: Ok, it's still ASCII art when you look at https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7d61ab67d0d5555a278216aa07347fafd1b6e42d2f8d8be3f2532e39766a2343/68747470733a2f2f6d617269616e2e616f6d6f72696465762e636f6d2f70726f6a656374732f636d64706c617970702f73637265656e73686f74322e706e67 , right? Does it have to be rendered via Terminal? Is that a criteria for passing the course?

Comment: I presume you can check that limit in Windows Terminal's settings.

Comment: _"didn't I ask already if there were any other ways to display large quantities ASCII characters efficiently in my question?"_ - You did, and _displaying_ them does _not_ require streaming escape sequences to an interpreter that then renders them. I'm suggesting that you by-pass that step to gain a lot.

Comment: @Eljay It looks like I'm not able to scroll up when the video finishes, that means it must be clearing the buffer every time no?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll definitely try another option later. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Seems very plausible.

Comment: I have a proper midway solution. Use [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/). I've actually used that myself and it will make your rendering pretty efficient by building up what needs to be sent to the renderer internally. It's based on old tech to optimize the transfer of bytes on slow lines. Used on a modern computer it seems "lightning fast".

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great! How do I get started with PDCurses? Is it a library I have to install and then use it in my code? Or can I install it?

Comment: @MattMoissat Yes, it's downloadable and then you just include `curses.h` and link with the proper library (in the docs). Instead of _you_ having to print escape sequences for colors etc, you will use the curses functions. There's probably 30 years of documentation online to get you started. It's basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487615/7582247) and the [pdcurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdcurses) tag.

Comment: Note though: I still think you'll get _a lot_ more throughput by just rendering it yourself on a canvas of some sort.

Comment: The slow speed of Windows terminal is being exaggerated just a tad, I think. I have an old implementation of John Conway's game of Life that uses Windows console output functions. With rather old/slow CPU/GPU (2.4 GHz Broadwell, GTX 1060) it updates an 80x50 console at over 350 frames per second. Granted, there are things that are quite a bit faster than that, but keeping up at 30 FPS is no problem at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm saying it's slow, not that it's the reason for not reaching fantastic FPSes. I also encouraged OP to measure where the real bottleneck is. It doesn't matter if Terminal is capable of 400 FPS if the video conversion doesn't produce 15+ FPS worth of ASCII info. There are many very measurable places in this pipeline.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Point is that the console is unlikely to be a real bottleneck. Unless you're right on the *very* edge between barely fast enough and not quite fast enough, faster terminal display isn't going to make a meaningful difference.

Comment: @JerryCoffin _"faster terminal display..."_ - No, not at all. I'm just advocating not producing a stream of instructions for a middleman that is not deviced for this. Better paint on a canvas. That's deviced exactly for this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: But the entire point of what he's doing is "display a video on a text terminal". I'd as well answer a question from you with: "forget being a software engineer--you should be an attorney; they make a lot more money."

Comment: @JerryCoffin I searched for the quoted "display a video on a text terminal" but I couldn't find it.  I relaxed it to "text terminal" but I still don't see it. Re: _"you should be an attorney; (reason)"_ - I actually don't know what I said that that's a reply to, but I don't care about (reason). I just love programming.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: "My project consists of creating small "ASCII videos" by converting frames from a video into ASCII images" (and elsewhere he directly mentions "windows terminal".

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, but he also refers to projects using other means even before I suggested helpers like PDCurses or painting on canvas. Oh well - I still think benching and finding out where the bottlenecks are is the way to go.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: When somebody care about speed, it's hard to argue against benchmarking as a good first step, no argument from me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote some code to do stream-style output directly to a Windows console, with color support.

```cpp
// WinBuf.hpp:

#pragma once
#include <ios>
#include <ostream>
#include <windows.h>

//! A C++ streambuf that writes directly to a Windows console
class WinBuf : public std::streambuf
{
    HANDLE h;

public:
    //! Create a WinBuf from an Windows handle
    //! @param h handle to a Windows console
    WinBuf(HANDLE h) : h(h) {}
    WinBuf(WinBuf const &) = delete;
    WinBuf &operator=(WinBuf const &) = delete;

    //! Return the handle to which this buffer is attached
    HANDLE handle() const { return h; }

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override
    {
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            DWORD written;
            WriteConsole(h, &c, 1, &written, nullptr);
        }
        return c;
    }

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(char_type const *s, std::streamsize count) override
    {
        DWORD written;
        WriteConsole(h, s, DWORD(count), &written, nullptr);
        return written;
    }
};

//! A C++ ostream that  writes via the preceding WinBuf
class WinStream : public virtual std::ostream
{
    WinBuf buf;

public:
    //! Create stream for a Windows console, defaulting to standard output
    WinStream(HANDLE dest = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))
        : buf(dest), std::ostream(&buf)
    {
    }

    //! return a pointer to the underlying WinBuf
    WinBuf *rdbuf() { return &buf; }
};

//! Provide the ability to set attributes (text colors)
class SetAttr
{
    WORD attr;

public:
    //! Save user's attribute for when this SetAttr object is written out
    SetAttr(WORD attr) : attr(attr) {}

    //! Support writing the SetAttr object to a WinStream
    //! @param w a WinStream object to write to
    //! @param c An attribute to set
    friend WinStream &operator<<(WinStream &w, SetAttr const &c)
    {
        WinBuf *buf = w.rdbuf();
        auto h = buf->handle();
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, c.attr);
        return w;
    }

    //! support combining attributes
    //! @param r the attribute to combine with this one
    SetAttr operator|(SetAttr const &r)
    {
        return SetAttr(attr | r.attr);
    }
};

//! Support setting the position for succeeding output
class gotoxy
{
    COORD coord;

public:
    //! Save position for when object is written to stream
    gotoxy(SHORT x, SHORT y) : coord{ .X = x, .Y = y} {}

    //! support writing gotoxy object to stream
    friend WinStream &operator<<(WinStream &w, gotoxy const &pos)
    {
        WinBuf *buf = w.rdbuf();
        auto h = buf->handle();
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, pos.coord);
        return w;
    }
};

//! Clear the "screen"
class cls
{
    char ch;

public:
    //! Create screen clearing object
    //! @param ch character to use to fill screen
    cls(char ch = ' ') : ch(ch) {}

    //! Support writing to a stream
    //! @param os the WinStream to write to
    //! @param c the cls object to write
    friend WinStream &operator<<(WinStream &os, cls const &c)
    {
        COORD tl = {0, 0};
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO s;
        WinBuf *w = os.rdbuf();
        HANDLE console = w->handle();

        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &s);
        DWORD written, cells = s.dwSize.X * s.dwSize.Y;
        FillConsoleOutputCharacter(console, c.ch, cells, tl, &written);
        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console, s.wAttributes, cells, tl, &written);
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, tl);
        return os;
    }
};

//! Provide some convenience instances of the SetAttr object
//! to (marginally) ease setting colors.
extern SetAttr red;
extern SetAttr green;
extern SetAttr blue;
extern SetAttr intense;

extern SetAttr red_back;
extern SetAttr blue_back;
extern SetAttr green_back;
extern SetAttr intense_back;
```

The attributes are defined in a matching .cpp file:

```cpp
// Winbuf.cpp:
#include "WinBuf.hpp"

SetAttr red{FOREGROUND_RED};
SetAttr green{FOREGROUND_GREEN};
SetAttr blue{FOREGROUND_BLUE};
SetAttr intense{FOREGROUND_INTENSITY};

SetAttr red_back{BACKGROUND_RED};
SetAttr green_back{BACKGROUND_GREEN};
SetAttr blue_back{BACKGROUND_BLUE};
SetAttr intense_back{BACKGROUND_INTENSITY};
```

Here's a quick demo/test program to show how it's used:

```cpp
// test_Winbuf.cpp
#include "winbuf.hpp"

int main()
{
    WinStream w;

    // the colors OR together, so red | green | blue gives white:
    auto color = red | green | blue | blue_back;

    w << color << cls() << gotoxy(10, 4) << "This is a string\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        w << "Line: " << i << "\n";

    w << (green | blue_back);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        w << "Line: " << i + 10 << "\n";

    w << gotoxy(20, 10) << "Stuck in the middle with you!\n";

    w << gotoxy(0, 30) << color << "The end\n";
}
```

At in my experience, this is quite a bit faster than using ANSI escape sequences (and, for what little it's worth, also works on older versions of Windows).

Comment: When I see _"Some time ago..."_ and this kind of code I'd expect it to be 10+ years ... and then I realized that `auto` _is_ that old by now. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Dates are fuzzy with age, but I probably originally wrote it closer to 25 years ago, and updated it something like 10 or 12 years ago.

Comment: I do love seeing nostalgia with updates.  Your old code makes sense still. That's where the upvote comes from.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Still seems to work, anyway (even if I do usually have to reboot to test Windows code any more).

Comment: Yeah the code seems to work for me too! @JerryCoffin amazing! I gave your solution an upvote. Is there any way that I can fine-tune the colours or are they predefined by windows? Edit: Windows Terminal (which is not cmd) seems to be supporting more than just blue red green etc.

Comment: @MattMoissat: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes